# Format Handsontable cell text

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Is it possible format only certain texts in handsontable ?

For eg. I want to make all the alphabets bold that match the string "mac".

So if there is a word "machine" in he table, the word must now be formatted as "**mac**hine"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [custom renderers](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/demo-custom-renderers.html), and inside the rederer function you can format the text using regEx. I think that is what you need.

cheers